# Server blocks api request symfony

Tags: symfony, server, request, response

i made a software in c# thats each 4 seconds request my server in symfony 5.4 to get products to print, but some time "may be a lot time" later my server start to block my request send me a html response write "Please wait while your request is being verified..." and my c# crash when this happen, this happen in browser too but works fine..
I was checking about this on the internet but and I saw that may be problem with firewall, token api and my friend told me about TTL, I've been trying allow the IP in firewall and doesn't work, about the API TOKEN, I don't know how this work, like, I saw something to create a new api token on cpanel but I don't know how to use that or if this is my solution, because in my API i don't use a token, each one can access /api/get_products_to_print and check JSON and work fine in the begin, I set TTL for 10 seconds and the JSON response and doen't work too, this problem is in one IP, if i change ip works again
I sent a picture about the response in browser

and this is the code that i get in C# response:
"<!doctype html>\n\n\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">\nOne moment, please...\n\nbody {\n    background: #F6F7F8;\n    color: #303131;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    margin-top: 45vh;\n    text-align: center;\n}\n\n\n\n

## Please wait while your request is being verified...

\n<form id="wsidchk-form" style="display:none;" action="/z0f76a1d14fd21a8fb5fd0d03e0fdc3d3cedae52f" method="get">\n<input type="hidden" id="wsidchk" name="wsidchk"/>\n\n\n(function(){\n    var west=+((+!+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+[])),\n        east=+((+!+[])+(+!+[]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])),\n        x=function(){try{return !!window.addEventListener;}catch(e){return !!0;} },\n        y=function(y,z){x() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",y,z) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",y);};\n    y(function(){\n        document.getElementById('wsidchk').value = west + east;\n        document.getElementById('wsidchk-form').submit();\n    }, false);\n})();\n\n\n"

[image: in browser]

Comment: It does not sounds like an issue related to symfony but rather a configuration issue on your server (cdn or whatever system you have). You mentioned that you've tried to allow the IP in the firewall - which does sound like the correct way to fix this issue. It would probably help you with getting more detailed answers if you can provide more information what kind of firewall system you have on your server (and maybe also the info how you tried to exclude the IP there and from which rules).